# Simple math in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am reading a select form value and multiplying it by 50 in jquery. I need to add a value of 1 to the qty that is returned by the select menu every time before multiplying by 50. How would I do that? The offending code looks like this.

```
 $('#selectform').val() *50);
```

If I use

```
 $('#selectform').val() +1 *50);
```

The result is not correct.

Answer (score 6):

Parentheses should be used.

```
 ($('#selectform').val()*1 + 1) *50;
```

Your current expression is interpreted as:

```
 var something = $('#selectform').val();
 var another   = 1 * 50;
 var result    = something + another
```

The `*1` after `.val()` is used to convert the string value to a number. If it's omitted, the expression will be interpreted as:

```
var something = $('#selectform').val() + "1";  //String operation
var result    = something * 50;    // something is converted to a number, and
                                   //    multiplied by 50
```

Answer (score 3):

The data from `$('#selectform').val()` is probably being treated as a string. 
Use `parseInt($('#selectform').val())` to convert it to an int before the multiply.

Answer (score 3):

Correct parentheses and use parseInt function -

```
(parseInt($('#selectform').val(),10) +1) *50;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at the [operator precedence in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).

Comment: ...or even just the [order of operations](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations) of basic mathematics. (aka [BEDMAS](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Mnemonics) etc)

Answer (score 0):

You need to force the addition to happen before the multiplication with parentheses:

```
bar myVal = ($("#selectform").val() + 1) * 50;
```