# How to update an integer value depending on the selection of a radiobutton?

Tags: jquery, html, radio-button

This should be a fairly  easy problem, but I don't know how to solve it and haven't found any appropriate answer to what I'm trying to do.

I have an html file with some text that, in very simple terms, has a string and two radio buttons. So something like this:

```
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>Some title</title>
      <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

      <div id="main">
         <p> 10 GB </p>
      </div>

      <div class="radioButtons" style="width: 100%">
        <p><input type="radio" name="radioLessGB" value="Less" align="absmiddle"/> I want less gigabytes(-3GB) </p>
            <p><input type="radio" name="radioMoreGB" value="More" align="absmiddle"/> I want more gigabytes (+5GB)</p>
      </div>
   </body>
   </html>
```

I need a way to update the value of the text (i.e. "10 GB") depending on the radiobutton that is selected. In particular, when the user selects the first radio button the integer value in the string above should go down by 3 **right away** (i.e. "10 GB" - 3 = "7 GB"),  and if the user selects the second radio button, the integer value should add 5 (i.e. "10 GB" + 5 = "15 GB").

To do this I guess I have to parse the string "10 GB" to get the Integer value and then add or subtract depending on the radiobutton chosen. Then update the string with the result. 
I don't want the user to click on some kind of "submit" button, the update of the number should be done 'on-the-fly' as the user toggles between radiobuttons.

I think this could be done with jQuery, I just don't know the way about it. Could someone more experienced help with sample code for a simple solution?!?

Thanks!!

Comment: StackOverflow is not the proper place for this question. We do not write your code for you. You need to do your own coding and if you aren't sure why something is not working as expected, post the code with an explanation of what you were expecting it to do, and what it is actually doing including all error messages. See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice).

Comment: Start by looking at the [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) handler.

Comment: Parsing the string won't really work. If you select "Less", and it subtracts 3 GB from the current 10 GB, then you end up with 7 GB, which is fine. However, if you then select "More", parse the string again, it will add 5 GB on to 7 GB, and give you a result of 12 GB - this is incorrect, assumedly it should be 15 GB, regardless of the previously selected option. Of course, you get the same issue if you select the options in the opposite order: 10 -> 15 -> 12.

Comment: @JohnConde - I was not looking for people to write the whole code of what Im trying to do, just asking for pointers as a beginner. I got good tips from some people quite fast, and I believe other users could benefit from their answers!! Sorry if it sounded like i wanted work to be done for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), you can simply do it as follows. try the [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/HrHLw/1/)

```
$("input").change(function() {
    $("#main").text((10 + parseInt($(this).val())) + " GB");
});
```

If you need to do this in **pure javascript**, use the following. try [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/HrHLw/1/)

```
function valChanged(ele) {
    document.getElementById('main1233').textContent = (10 + parseInt(ele.value)) + " GB";
}
```

Comment: Hej Wolf, this is exactly what I was looking for!!! Thank you very much! Great way to start learning jquery by examples.

Answer (score 1):

I won't give a full code answer here, just pointers to help you along:

1. Don't parse strings to perform calculations, just use numbers (or at least a numeric string). Put the value of `10` inside a special `data-xxx` attribute. You can access those data later with [`$(el).data('xxx')`](http://api.jquery.com/data/):

   ```
   <div id="main" data-value="10">
   ```
2. Do the same for the `<input>` elements to keep the "delta" value, e.g. `-3` and `+5` or use their respective values with [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).
3. If any of the radio buttons is clicked (detect event using [`.on('change', fn)`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)) you add whatever delta value is selected to the value inside `#main`.
4. Display the formatted value of the sum using [`.text(sum + ' GB')`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

Comment: To save me throwing together a test, do you know off-hand if jQuery would treat the `data-value` attribute as an integer or a string?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist It will be a string, so either casting or coercion is required to do math with it.

Comment: @Jack Thanks for the hints! It is valuable to what I'm trying to do!  I guess using parseInt() would also work to do the math, right?!

Comment: @djjupa Yeah, definitely. `parseInt()` would do just fine!

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is one avenue to accomplish this fairly easy task. You'll want to isolate your #main div. Then use jQuery to grab that current value, and do the math with the radio button's onClick (or in jQuery: `.click(function()`. I'd suggest putting the value of the radio option within the input tag.

check out: [Simple math in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7971292/simple-math-in-jquery)

Comment: Don't use `onclick` for radio and checkbox inputs, use `onchange` instead. You can use your keyboard, rather than your mouse, to change the checked state of a radio button or checkbox - `onclick` won't recognise that because a click hasn't taken place.